# How to set a Drawable Resource on ImageButton's background?

Tags: java, android

I'm coding my first app. I'm aware that you can set it through the class' xml, but because the way the app works, I need to be able to set the drawable on the fly.
Short question is: I have a xml file for a certain graphic, how can I set an ImageButton's background to that in the .java file by using a string? (in @drawable)
Long details:
I'm making a part where people choose the suit (of cards), and the cards of the specific suit appears. I want to do this by having 13 pre-set ImageButton objects (they can click them after), which has no specified background to begin with. The cards are labelled c1.xml, c2.xml, ... etc, each points to image files that are either to depict the state of being pressed or not being pressed. I want to have the Java class set what background drawables to use for the Imagebuttons after the suit has been selected. I'm having trouble with how to set the drawable by only knowing the name of the xml file and the directory @drawable/card.xml. The string would be that path or equivalent. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setBackgroundDrawable()` and use `R.drawable.drawable_file` to set drawable.

Comment: would it be possible to have a string "R.drawable.file" and make a drawable from that? and thank you! =D